# How to check multiple comparisons in PHP not using an if or case?

Tags: php

So I know you could do something simple like this to set a variable equal to one thing if the condition is true and one thing if it is false.

```
$height > 70 ? $output = "Taller than 6 foot" : $output = "Shorter than 6 foot";
```

But how would I go through and check multiple things like this not using an if statement? For example, if I wanted to check if height was between 5 and 6, between 4 and 5, between 3 and 4 and more, and then only echo out one $result based on which category $height fell in, how would I do that? Could I just add something useless after the : such as a variable I would never use?

Comment: What you're using there is a *ternary* statement - it *is* an `if` condition. You do not want to nest these if at all possible because they become hard to read and follow. You might consider `switch()`

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant by case in the question. I want to know how to do this without using the if or the switch. I know it would be easy using one of those, but it's just an exercise to try and do it without either.

Comment: If you don't want either of those you're really out of options.

Comment: What Jay said x1000. However, if just an exercise and you don't care about reading the code later on, you can nest ternary statements. I would just suggest using parenthesis to group them as the assignment is a little odd otherwise and non-obvious. `$output = $height > 70 ? 'tall' : ($height > 60 ? 'average' : 'short');` is the equivalent of `if($height > 70) $output = 'tall'; elseif($height > 60) $output = 'average'; else $output = 'short';`

Answer (score 1):

The only way to parameterize this would be to use `switch` which is mostly the same as using ifs but with a multiple verifications. Sadly, there's no shorter way to write this. (There might be, but they might be cumbersome to write / read which is not always an advantage!).

Here's a switch / case statement that uses multiple conditions. Usually, you pass the variable to the `switch` statement and you use the `case` statements with variables or possible values, but since the possible values are conditions, you need to pass `true` as a parameter as this is the value to be expected. You can reverse this by passing `false` if needed.

```
switch(true){
    case ($my_number > 3):
        echo "Greater than 3";
    break;

    case ($my_number <= 3):
        echo "Smaller or equal to 3";
    break;
}
```

Comment: I know it would be easy with an if or a switch, but it's just some exercise in a book that's stumped me.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if I'm getting your question right, but you can omit the left side of the ternary statement : 

```echo $number > 3?:'Not higher than 3';```

But the right side needs something, so passing null as a fallback or an empty string would also work. 

```echo $number > 3?'Higher than 3':null;```

Answer (score 0):

you can make nested conditions:

```
$output = ($height < 6 && $height > 5) ? 'something' : (($height <= 3) ? 'less t. 3' : 'over 4')
```

but this is not really readable, I would avoid this, syntax with multiple conditions is better with if/switch